# Fastest way to send rendered emails to SendGrid

Tags: rest, email, go, sendgrid

We have an in-house (Golang based) rendering service that, besides adding bunch of config values to email, simply merges the template with data. The next step is to send these rendered emails via SendGrid.

I can see from SendGrid's API documentation that they offer REST api and SMTP api. Lets say, if we want to send out 600k emails, then making 600k rest requests, even with some concurrency, wont be the most efficient way. I also went through their article about choosing [SMTP or REST api](https://sendgrid.com/blog/which-protocol-should-i-use-to-send-email-smtp-or-rest/) but no clear answer there as well.

What is most preferred/efficient route for the situation described above?

Comment: What's unclear about the answer they provide? There are 3 cases where they say that the REST api would be preferred, otherwise pipelining the messages over a single SMTP connection will be fastest.

Comment: `3000 requests/sec is the maximum rate at which you may call v3 Mail endpoint.` That seems reasonable...

Comment: There also is an [official Go client library](https://github.com/sendgrid/smtpapi-go). Take a look.

Comment: @JimB: that doesnt say if its possible to connect directly to their SMTP, which saves the hassle of setting up a local postfix server, for example.

Comment: @MDrollette that endpoint is still in beta and not recommended to use in production

Comment: @LutzHorn thats just a library to add SendGrid specific SMTP headers to SMTP request. It doesnt do any SMTP connection management for you.

Comment: You can use any SMTP client you want. https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/index.html#-SMTP-Relay but you'll need to manage pipelining and connection pools yourself. You'll also probably want a worker queue to process the email sending for resiliency.

Answer (score 0):

I use to send to sendgrid through basic smtp.  I'd get about 3 emails a second going out that way.  I switched to their api where I basically send about 500 per json POST and i find each of those posts takes a couple 100 ms max so now, I can send 15,000 emails in minutes max.  Sendgrid does get that out fast also which is quite nice.

Comment: With sendgrid's REST api, is it possible to send multiple emails per POST request? Because for us every email is different. I checked their V3 api documentation but it seems that `content` block only accepts different mime types of same email.